# Is there a way to do multiple substitutions using regsub?

Tags: regex, tcl

Is it possible to have do different substitutions in an expression using regsub?

example:

```
set a ".a/b.c..d/e/f//g"
```

Now, in this expression, is it possible to substitute 
"`.`" as "`yes`" 
 "`..`" as "`no`" 
 "`/`" as "`true`" 
 "`//`" as "`false`" in a single regsub command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a `regsub`, no. There's a long-standing feature request for this sort of thing (which requires substitution with the result of evaluating a command on the match information) but it's not been acted on to date.

But you can use `string map` to do what you want in this case:

```
set a ".a/b.c..d/e/f//g"
set b [string map {".." "no" "." "yes" "//" "false" "/" "true"} $a]
puts "changed $a to $b"
# changed .a/b.c..d/e/f//g to yesatruebyescnodtrueetrueffalseg
```

Note that when building the map, if any from-value is a prefix of another, the longer from-value should be put first. (This is because the `string map` implementation checks which change to make in the order you list them in…)

---

It's possible to use `regsub` and `subst` to do multiple-target replacements in a two-step process, but I don't advise it for anything other than very complex cases! A nice `string map` is far easier to work with.

Comment: The missing feature is an equivalent of Perl's `s///e`. Total overkill for this case…

Answer (score 2):

You may also try to do it yourself. This is a draft `proc` which you could use as a starting point. It is not production ready, and you must be carefull because substitutions after the first one work on already substituted string.

These are the parameters:

- `options` is a list of options that will be passed to every call to `regsub`
- `resubList` is a list of key/value pairs, where the key is a regular expression and the value is a substitution
- `string` is the string you want to substitute

This is the procedure, and it simply calls `regsub` multiple times, once for every element in `resubList` and, at the end, it returns the final string.

```
proc multiregsub {options resubList string} {
    foreach {re sub} $resubList {
        set string [regsub {*}$options -- $re $string $sub]
    }
    return $string
}
```

Comment: Note that this will produce unexpected results for cases such as {a A A b} since the replaced string is iterated multiple times. This is different then string map (http://wiki.tcl.tk/2819).

Comment: Yes, I know; maybe I should be more explicit about these caveats.